# In python, What does this means 1, 2 == 1, 2?

Tags: python

Can someone explain output?
I wanted to check for equality of two numbers but didn't work out properly.

```
Input: 1, 2 == 1, 2
Output: (1, False, 2)
```

Comment: You must have parentheses around the numbers. The current code displays `1`, evaluates `2 == 1`, then displays `2`. If you add parentheses, it will check the equality.

Comment: A python tuple has been created as suggested add () for the tuple check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a tuple with 3 elements, namely, `1`, `2 == 1`, and `2`. The first and last element are integer literals so it might not come as a surprise that their values in Python evaluate to `1` and `2` respectively.
The element, `2 == 1` is a single expression that evaluates to `False` because `2` does not equal `1`.

If you are looking to check the equality of two tuples with two elements, `(1,2)` and `(1,2)` you  must do `(1, 2) == (1, 2)` so Python knows which elements separated by commas to treat as a single element.

In the REPL you can figure this out by comparing what you have with

```
>>> (1, 2) == (1, 2)
True
>>> (1, 3) == (1, 2)
False
>>> (3, 1) == (2, 1)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a tuple of 3 elements, int, boolean and int.

If you want a simutaneous comparison use

```py
[1, 2] == [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 1, 2 == 1, 2
```

which is

```
print 1, False, 2 //since 1 not equal to 2
```

which will output

> 1 False 2

Answer (score 0):

Actually 2==1 will give you false since 2 is not equal to one.So a better way of doing this is using if statements

```
a = 1
b = 2
if b > a:
  print(b + " is greater than " + a)
elif a == b:
print("a and b are equal")
else:
print("a is greater than b")
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your code, it is a simple equality checking.  It returns true if both the operands are true, in your case, it is 1 == 2 so it will return false as both are not the same. 
If you to compare them then add braces over them.

Answer (score -1):

The order of operations is not what you think.  == has a higher priority than the commas.  So you are creating a 3-tuple with the following elements:

```
1
the result of the Boolean test to see whether 2 equals 1
2
```

This may be what you intend, try it:

```
>>> (1,2) == (1,2)
True
```